# Incorrect `update statement` using IN operator with Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have a function which is wanted to execute a statement like below:

```
UPDATE coupon_users SET status = status | '1' WHERE id IN ('3','4')
```

And in `coupon_users` model, I wrote a method like below do to:

```
/**
* @param array $ids        #array(3,4)
* @param array $status     #1
*/
public function updateStatus(array $ids, $status)
{
    $result = $this->_db->query(
        "UPDATE {$this->_name} SET status = status | ? WHERE id IN (?)",
        array(
            $status,
            $ids
        )
    )->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

#### But the query is always:

```
UPDATE coupon_users SET status = status | '1' WHERE id IN ('Array')
```

I don't know what am I wrong here, please help me, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PDO documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (Zend_Db uses PDO as its DB access backend):

> You cannot bind multiple values to a single named parameter in, for
>   example, the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

So, you'll probably need to prepare a bit further your query, so that it contains as many markers as elements in the array. A possible solution could be the following:

```
// Compose the query
$queryToExecute = "UPDATE {$this->_name} SET status = status | ? WHERE id IN (";
$questionMarks = array();
for ($id in $ids) {
    $questionMarks[] = '?';
}
$queryToExecute .= implode(',', $questionMarks);
$queryToExecute .= ')';

// $queryToExecute should have the format "UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (?,?,?,...?)"

// Execute it
$result = $this->_db->query(
    $queryToExecute,
    array($status, $ids)
)->execute();
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
public function updateStatus(array $ids, $status)
{
    $result = $this->_db->query(
        "UPDATE {$this->_name} SET status = ? WHERE id IN (?)",
        array(
            $status,
            implode(',',$ids)
        )
    )->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Update:

Have you tried?:

```
$this->_db->update($this->_name, array('status'=>$status), array('id IN (?)'=>$ids));
```

I haven't tested it, it also depends on what $this->_db is an instance of

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.update

Comment: See my update, it might help you more, otherwise the link tells you want you need to do

Comment: Thanks, and you can see that I need the statement: `status = status | ?` ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
public function updateStatus(array $ids, $status)
{
    $inarray=   implode(',',$ids);
    $result = $this->_db->query(
        "UPDATE {$this->_name} SET status = status | ? WHERE id IN (?)",
        array(
            $status, 
            $inarray
        )
    )->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me.

```
     $existingImagesIds = array(1, 2, 3, 7);

     $where = $pImgModel->getAdapter()->quoteInto("id in (?) ", $existingImagesIds);

     $pImgModel->update(array('status' => '0'), $where);
```